# How can check whether Perl compilation has already completed?

Tags: perl

I have some code the requires the application to be completely loaded and compiled before it should be executed.

Is there a way to check whether my Perl program is still in the compilation stage?

I have something that works, but there must be a better way:

```
sub check_compile {
  printf("checking\n");
  foreach my $depth (0..10) {
    my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine) = caller($depth);
    last unless (defined($package));

    printf("  %s %s %s %s %s\n", $depth, $package, $filename, $line, $subroutine);

    if ($subroutine =~ /::BEGIN$/) {
      printf("in compile\n");
      return 1;
    }

  }

  printf("not in compile\n");
  return 0;
}


BEGIN {
  check_compile();
}

use subpkg;

check_compile();
```

and subpkg.pm contains:

```
package subpkg;

use strict;
use warnings;

printf("initing subpkg\n");
main::check_compile();

1; # successfully loaded
```

Comment: Why not simply set a global flag when you are done compiling, and check the value of that flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your code doesn't make much use of `eval` - otherwise compilation will be taking place 'mixed in' with execution - but you might review the use of `INIT` and similar blocks [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) as a possible way to simplify this.

> INIT blocks are run just before the
>   Perl runtime begins execution, in
>   "first in, first out" (FIFO) order.

Comment: Of course. Now that you mention it, it seems obvious. Still seems like Perl'd have a status var reflecting this.

Comment: `eval` isn't the only way to mix compilation into run-time. `require` and `do` will also pull in new code and compile it during normal execution.

Answer (score 2):

See [`$^S` in `perlvar`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#S):

> Current state of the interpreter.

```
    $^S         State
    ---------   -------------------
    undef       Parsing module/eval
    true (1)    Executing an eval
    false (0)   Otherwise
```

> The first state may happen in $SIG{**DIE**} and $SIG{**WARN**} handlers.

```
    BEGIN { print "Compile $^S\n" }
    print "Run-time $^S\n";
    eval { print "Eval $^S\n" };
```

---

```
    Compile
    Run time 0
    Eval 1
```

Comment: `$^S` is also undefined for compile-time `eval`s (say, an `eval` in a `BEGIN` block)

Comment: a case that I didn't have in my question was other packages that are use'd. Initialization code there happens when $^S is true. At that point, there's more compilation to be done.

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but AFAIK should do it:

```
sub main_run_phase_entered {
    local $@;
    ! eval q!use warnings FATAL => 'all'; CHECK{} 1!
}
```

Update: nope, fails for me (with 5.10.1) in an END{} block.  The CHECK{} doesn't run, but doesn't complain either.